# React passing onClick value from one class to another

Tags: reactjs, api, react-router, react-props

In Tournaments.js I have a list of Tournament names each with unique ID's which are fetched from an API. Now whenever I click on one of these tournament names, I get it's ID but I need to pass this ID to Template.js where I can fetch tournament data based on the Tournament ID that was clicked. I am trying to do something with passing props from child to parent but I am completely lost right now.

Tournament.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Template from './template';

const API = 'http://localhost:8080/api/tournaments';

class Tournaments extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API)
    .then((Response) => Response.json())
    .then((findresponse) => {
      console.log(findresponse)
      this.setState({
        data:findresponse,
      })
    })
  }

  reply_click(event) {
    var targetId = event.target.getAttribute('id');
    console.log(targetId);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
              {
                this.state.data.map((dynamicData, key) =>
                <div>
                  <a href={"/#/template"} id={dynamicData.id} onClick={this.reply_click}>{dynamicData.name}</a>
                  <a href={"/#/addTeams"}><button type="button" class="btn-lisa">Edit</button></a>
                  <Template name={dynamicData.id}></Template>
                </div>
                )
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Tournaments;
```

Template.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';
import Tournaments from "./Tournaments";
import './template.css';
import './index.css';

const tournyAPI = 'http://localhost:8080/api/tournaments';
const teamAPI = 'http://localhost:8080/api/teams'

class template extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(tournyAPI)
    .then((Response) => Response.json())
    .then((findresponse) => {
      this.setState({
        tournydata:findresponse.filter(res => res.id === 18),
      })
    })
```

So basically my goal is to use targetID from Tournament.js in place of the '18' in the ComponentDidMount in Template.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep this value in the parent's component `state` and pass it as a prop to child.

When your `onClick` is fired you should update parents `state` so updated `props` will be passed to child.

Here is the code:

**Tournament.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Template from './template';

const API = 'http://localhost:8080/api/tournaments';

class Tournaments extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      targetId: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API)
    .then((Response) => Response.json())
    .then((findresponse) => {
      console.log(findresponse)
      this.setState({
        data:findresponse,
      })
    })
  }

  reply_click = id => {
    return () => {
        this.setState({ targetId: id })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
              {
                this.state.data.map((dynamicData, key) =>
                <div>
                  <a href={"/#/template"} onClick={this.reply_click(dynamicData.id)}>{dynamicData.name}</a>
                  <a href={"/#/addTeams"}><button type="button" class="btn-lisa">Edit</button></a>
                  <Template name={dynamicData.id} targetId={this.state.targetId}></Template>
                </div>
                )
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Tournaments;
```

**Template.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';
import Tournaments from "./Tournaments";
import './template.css';
import './index.css';

const tournyAPI = 'http://localhost:8080/api/tournaments';
const teamAPI = 'http://localhost:8080/api/teams'

class template extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(tournyAPI)
    .then((Response) => Response.json())
    .then((findresponse) => {
      this.setState({
        tournydata: findresponse.filter(res => res.id === this.props.targetId),
      })
    })
```

But do it using `componentDidUpdate` instead of `componentDidMount` if you want keep updated your **Template** component after every changing of `targetId`.

Like this:

**Template.js**

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.targetId !== this.props.targetId) {
       fetch(tournyAPI)
       .then((Response) => Response.json())
       .then((findresponse) => {
       this.setState({
          tournydata:findresponse.filter(res => res.id === this.props.targetId),
       })
      })
    }
}
```

If you need to do it at once during first rendering just add check if `targetId` is not `null` in your `Tournament` component.

Something like this:

**Tournament.js**

```
render() {
    ...
    {this.state.targetId ? <Template name={dynamicData.id} targetId={this.state.targetId}></Template> : null }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Tried this but {this.props.targetId} returns undefined in Template.js

Also, does <Template targetId={this.state.targetId}></Template> need to be inside render or does it work outside of the render aswell?

Comment: @Ferder I've updated your `reply_click` function in my answer. Use it like this.

Comment: @Ferder how did u tried, with which one? `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: componentDidUpdate

Comment: @Ferder try to use it with updated `reply_click` function and change `onClick` as I did

Answer (score 0):

Add `targetID` to your parent state and pass as prop to child:

```
reply_click(event) {
  var targetId = event.target.getAttribute('id');
  this.setState({ targetID });
}
<Template targetID={this.state.targetID}
```

In `Template` you can access it with `this.props.targetID`.

You need to use `componentDidUpdate` though, see [React Child component don't update when parent component's state update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075835/react-child-component-dont-update-when-parent-components-state-update/50075902#50075902)

Comment: This method also gives me the Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined.

Comment: You need to bind the method in your constructor: `this.reply_click = this.reply_click.bind(this)`, or declare it as `reply_click = event => {`.

Comment: Thanks, got rid of the error but inside Template.js {this.props.targetID} still returns undefined

Comment: Did you initialise the state with `this.state = { targetID: null }`? You also need to change your `componentDidMount` to `componentDidUpdate`; see the link I gave above.

Answer (score 0):

In your example it's very easy as you are rendering `<Template>` in loop you can pass it as param

## Problem 1

React purpose is not to manipulate dom like this `var targetId = event.target.getAttribute('id')` You have this id, why you are fetching it from DOM? Instead of that accept it as param

```
 <a href={"/#/template"} id={dynamicData.id} onClick={(e) => this.reply_click(e, dynamicData.id)}>{dynamicData.name}</a>
```

and

```
reply_click(event, targetId) {

    console.log(targetId);
  }
```

Never ever query DOM in React. You will get mess and errors because of unmounted elements and etc. React uses JSDom (in memory) not Real DOM

## Problem 2

Just pass it as param

and call setState inside `reply_click`

```
reply_click(event, targetId) {

    console.log(targetId);
    this.setState({targetID: targetId})
  }
```

Comment: Tried using this method, now I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined.
I also added targetID to the this.state part of the constructor

Comment: You didnt change link to what I sent ... it has onClick={() => this.reply_click} which will wrap the call back with this context